# Ajuda com number_format php

Tags: php

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
$subjects[$i]['mark_final'] = number_format($final,1);
```

Que retorna exemplo: 8.0 (até aqui tudo ok).

O problema é quando divido por 4.

```
$subjects[$i]['mark_final'] = number_format($final, 1) / 4;
```

Ele me retorna 2, gostaria que retornasse 2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilize o [number_format](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.number-format.php) após efetuar a divisão, assim:

```
$subjects[$i]['mark_final'] = number_format(($final/4), 1);
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente. Muito obrigado. JrD.

Answer (score 2):

Para obter o retorno como um valor `float` você pode retornar assim:

```
$subjects[$i]['mark_final'] = number_format(($final / 4), 1, ".");
```